# How to add a flatbuffer object to a new object?

Tags: rust, flatbuffers

I understand how to use the `FlatBufferBuilder` and specific type builder (e.g., `MyNestedTableBuilder`) to get the `WIPOffset` and then use that to get the `finished_data` buffer (`&[u8]`). I then have been using `get_root` to get an object based on the buffer, so now I have an instance of `MyNestedTable`. Then I need to pass that to another function and create a new table instance via a new builder, `MyTable`, that has the field `add_my_nested_table`. I cannot see how to do this without unpacking `MyNestedTable` and rebuilding it again (which seems very inefficient). I am sure there is a good way to do this, I just haven't found it, even after studying the generated code and API.

Generally we have a need to pass objects around and reuse them, over the network or via API calls in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyNestedTable` isn't really an object, it is a handle to data inside the serialized data (your `[u8]`), and any field accesses look up this data on the fly.

None of the base APIs for any of the FlatBuffers supported languages (including Rust) have code generated that allows automatic re-serializing, since that is not a frequent operation in most use cases (you already have the serialized data).

The way to do it is through the optional "object API", supported in C++ and some other languages, but [not yet in Rust](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5132). As you can see, CasperN is working on such an API.

Until then, you may consider using `nested_flatbuffer` or some other construct to directly pass the serialized data to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly, I now see why it works that way. I will either rebuild the new object by reading the `MyNestedTable` or perhaps store the bytes like `nested_flatbuffer`.